# SVN client on an encrypted file system

Tags: windows, svn, encryption

I'm using tortoise SVN to check out & check in files to my SVN repository. I want to encrypt my local file system (the system that runs the tortoise SVN client, not the SVN repository).

My question is, will tortoise SVN work correctly? Will it be able to commit changes to the repository (in unencrypted format) if the changed files are on an encrypted system? Will I be able to check out these files later from a different system correctly, without having the encryption certificate?

I'm using built-in windows 7 encryption to encrypt the file system.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this might not work?

Comment: I thought maybe it will try to compare the encrypted version with the version in the repository, and then update the repository with the encrypted version... What you say makes sense, and I also assumed that from the SVN client's perspective the file is in it's unencrypted format, so it would compare the unencrypted version with that of the repository and send the unencrypted version when committing, but I was afraid to experiment on the chance that it did send the encrypted files and ruin the repository for everyone... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, of course. File system encryption works on a system level and doesn't change the content of the files.

Comment: Thanks, with your answer I felt confident enough to experiment and can confirm that the client sends the unencrypted file to the repository.